# Highcharts chart keep increasing its height on browser resize

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vue2-highcharts

I have a couple of Highcharts charts on my web application. It's a Laravel and Vue.js application (built on the top of Laravel Spark). I am using Highcharts 6.1.1 and vue2-highcharts (uperman66/vue-highcharts).

When I resize the width of the browser (a practical case is changing orientation on a mobile device), I see that the height of the chart keeps on increasing. And, I guess as a result of which, Highcharts keeps decreasing `tickInterval` (which was not set - default value) of `yAxis`.

Here is how it looks when the page loads:

[image: When page loads]

But after resizing the width:

[image: Top of the chart after resizing]

[image: Bottom of the chart after resizing]

Well, the chart was too high to take one screenshot.

I tried to reproduce the error in [CodeSandbox](https://ovmjpkzp9.codesandbox.io/#/Chart), it is working fine there. Any idea why is it happening like this?

Comment: I can only answer this for ChartJS, where you need to set two options: `responsive: true` and `maintainAspectRatio: false`. I suppose there is an equivalent for HighCharts. The problems occurs from Vue redrawing the canvas. More information: https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/84

Comment: @BennettDams Not sure how to set `responsive: true` and `maintainAspectRatio: false` in HighCharts or vue2-highcharts. But I found a workaround. I am explicitly setting up the height to 400 and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why Highcharts is behaving like this but I got a workaround. I am have explicitly set the height of the chart to 400 and it works now.

```
...
chart: {
    ...
    height: 400
},
...
```